# Linking a navbar across multiple pages without server side scripting

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, navbar

I want to link a navbar across multiple pages of my website without using a server side scripting language like PHP. I'm using the jQuery load function at the bottom of my pages to load the navbar into the #navbar element. This almost works, but the problem is the same file path gets specified for directories that are at different levels of depth in my project (ex):

```
<a class="expandable-link" href="services/index.html">Services</a>
```

This path would work fine from my main index file (site/index.html), but would not work from my services directory index file (services/services/index.html).

From the research I've done, one person said this needs to be done with a server side scripting language. Is there anyway to modify the paths based on where the load function is called so that this can be accomplished with Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the relative uri path:

```
services/index.html
```

use the relative-to-root uri path:

```
/services/index.html
```